# Espson Stylus Workforce 320 SX218 Lubuntu, Need to clean print head/nozzles

Tags: lubuntu, printing, 15.04, epson

It's in the title! =) ;) I'm running Lubuntu 15.04 and can't find out how to clean the printer head/nozzles. I'm sure I've seen it somewhere but I can't remember. And yes, I've got CUPS installed and the correct driver for my particular printer.

Thanks =)

P.S: This might turn into a different discussion if cleaning the head/nozzles doesn't work. =)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use menu in the printer itself. The printer should have a display. There must be an option to test/clean nozzles.

Stylus Workforce 320 has this functionality. You can look at the printer's manual to do it.

Press menu button, then go to 'Maintenance' -> 'Head cleaning'.

If the printer has no features to do it there, then you could install escputil.

```
sudo apt-get install escputil
```

You can check nozzles by

```
escputil -n
```

and clean by

```
escputil -c
```

There are some other options, you can see them in

```
man escputil
```

Comment: Nope! =) Hahhaha That's the first thing I looked for. Basic stuff. =D

Comment: And what's your obsession with me dude? Hahaha =) lol. Do you just spend a lot of time on "ask" and just happen to think that my questions are interesting or something? =P

Comment: You did not look well. ))

Comment: I've just considered the setup more closely, and oddly enough, you appear to have to press two buttons at once. =/ Weird.